# 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' api json data django

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

I am sending data through post request in json but not geting password in view

JsonFormet

```
{"email": "xyz@gmail.com", "password":123456 }
```

I am geting email id like this

```
email = request.data['email']
password = request.data['password']
```

But not getting password

```
Error

'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Event i try encode but still getting error

```
password = request.data['password'].encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're passing an integer in the JSON and you don't cast it as string later while Django expects a string for the password.

So make sure you cast the password as string:

```
password = str(request.data['password'])
```